# Oracle Forms 6.0 Error while running a simple Master Detail form

Tags: forms, oracle, oracle10g

I have built a form with two tables **sales_info_7** and **sales_details_7** but everytime i have tried to run the form it gives the following error(attached with this question).can anybody please help me out with this?would appreciate it.

Tables used :

```
SQL> desc sales_detail_7
 Name                            Null?    Type
 ------------------------------- -------- ----
 SALES_DETAIL_ID                          NUMBER
 MEMO_NO                                  NUMBER
 ITEM_ID                                  NUMBER
 RATE                                     NUMBER
 QTY                                      NUMBER

SQL> desc sales_info_7
 Name                            Null?    Type
 ------------------------------- -------- ----
 MEMO_NO                         NOT NULL NUMBER
 SALES_DATE                               DATE
```

Screenshot : **FRM-40010**
[image: form_error]

Answer (score 1):

Are you running your form called from a menu? It looks like your directory is not specified in FORMS60_PATH. 
Can you run your other forms except this? What about if you just run the form from Forms Designer?

Comment: I am running my form from 'Oracle Forms Builder'.it is still showing me the above mentioned error message.can you please check the printscreen of the FORMS60_PATH directory i am attaching here?please let me know if it is correct.

[![registry.jpg](https://s17.postimg.org/70jzl6rfz/registry.jpg)](https://postimg.org/image/4j88dx7jf/)

Comment: When you have multiple directories, make sure you separate them with semicolons. I cannot see a semicolon separating your working directory to the one that is previously there.
e.g: c:\oracle\tools;E:\newdir\xxx;c:\temp;c:\folder2\test\yyy